# Initiate IBAction of a UIButton on Return key

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, ibaction, uitextfielddelegate

I have a SignUp Form which includes a number of `UITextfields` and `UIButton`. I have set up `UITextfield` delegates so that the when user starts editing on a `UITextfield` and presses the return key it goes to the next `UITextfield`.

[image: SignUp Form]

DoB, ISD Code, Gender and Nationality are `UIButtons` which have `IBActions`, and rest of them are `UITextfields`

Is it possible to initiate a `IBAction` of a `UIButton` on pressing the `return` key from a Textfield. So that the user can sequentially add the necessary data to the signup form.

What i have done so far ..

```
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool{

    if let nextField = textField.superview?.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1) as? UITextField
    {
        nextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    else {
        // Not found, so remove keyboard.
        signupScrollView .setContentOffset(CGPoint( x: 0, y: 0), animated: true)
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
    // Do not add a line break
    return false
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    signupScrollView .setContentOffset(CGPoint( x: 0, y: textField.center.y-200), animated: true)

}
```

Comment: You don't trigger the `@IBAction` as such, you just call the same function that the `@IBaction` calls.

Comment: you want to call `@IBAction` Programatically right? Like I am on `Email` field and I press on `return` key from keyboard than `DoB` action should fire.

Comment: @Kuldeep yes...

Comment: what if i call the IBAction in the else part and call the initiate the textfield delegate at the end of the IBAction?

Comment: @alpha47 Are your `button`s and `textField`s having common sequential tags?

Comment: @alpha47 check my answer. If not then you could do the tag trick or we'll try a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `textField`s and `button`s have a common sequence of tags, you can basically do something like the following:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    let nextView = textField.superview?.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1)

    if let nextTextField = nextView as? UITextField {
        //next view is a textField so make next textField first responder
        nextTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    //just this extra case is required
    else if let nextButton = nextView as? UIButton {
        //next view is a button so call it's associated action
        //(assuming your button's @IBAction is on the Touch Up Inside event)
        nextButton.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)

        /*
         a button's action will be performed so if you want to 
         perform the return action on the textField then either
         return true/false. Decide that as per your requirement
         */
        return true
    }
    else {
        //...
    }
    
    //...
}
```

---

The above logic is enough to answer your question but works only when the user is on a `textField` and has tapped on the keyboard's `Return` button.

Now... the thing is that on the end of a button actions, if you want to continue to the next view; `textField` or `button`, you can **either<sup>1</sup>** explicitly code to make the next view active.

Example:

- After `ISD Code` is done you could make the mobile `textField` as first responder
- After `Gender` is done, you could call the button action for `Nationality`

#### Or<sup>2</sup>...

We can modify the solution to handle `textField` as well as `button`s alike with a common helper function, that we will call `goNext(from:)` to be implemented in `textFieldShouldReturn(_:)` as well as after the button is to complete it's intended logic flow.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let nextView = goNext(from: textField)
    
    if let nextTextField = nextView as? UITextField {
        //Next field was a textField so keyboard should stay
        return false
    }
    
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

@discardableResult func goNext(from sender: UIView) -> UIView? {
    let nextView = sender.superview?.viewWithTag(sender.tag + 1)
    print(nextView?.tag ?? "No view with tag \(sender.tag + 1)")
    
    if let nextTextField = nextView as? UITextField {
        nextTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    else if let nextButton = nextView as? UIButton {
        nextButton.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    else {
        print("Done")
        signupScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), 
                                          animated: true)
        sender.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    return nextView
}
```

Now for the button part, you need to perform `goNext(from: button)` whenever the associated button has completed it's logic.

Example:

- User has successfully selected Date of Birth: You should then be calling

  `goNext(from: dobButton)`

Comment: @alpha47 sure, let me know :)

Comment: getting an error at `else if let nextButton = nextView as? UIButton` 
" Use of unresolved identifier 'nextView' "

Comment: check `nextView`. you should have `let nextView = textField.superview?.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1)` before you do the `if let`

Comment: that did the trick, i had to add `isdButton.sendAction(for: .touchUpInside)` at the end of DoB's Action. and to initiate `Mobile` textfield, made it the first responder at the end of `isdButton`'s Action..

Comment: @alpha47 awesome! but you should not call `goNext(from:)` immediatey at the end of `DoB` button's action but rather after the user has selected the date of birth.

Comment: @alpha47 Check updated answer. Better case handling for you. Anyways... glad to help and... happy coding :)